# How to debug crash, when backtrace starts with zero

Tags: c++, debugging, coredump

my long running application crashes randomly with segmentation fault. When trying to debug the generated coredump, I get stuck with wierd stacktrace:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0 __memmove_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:2582
No locals.
#1 0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

How it can happen, that the backtrace starts at 0x00000000?
What can I do to debug this issue more? I can't run it in gdb as it may take even a week till the crash occures.

Comment: Something nuked the stack pointer. That really sucks.You're going to have to approach this from the other side and divide and conquer to narrow in on the crash site and the actual killer. Start planting log messages in the code and see how far the program gets before it crashes. Use the information gathered to improve the log messages or add more. Yay if you can track and kill it with a few log messages! But if you can't, go back to gdb with breakpoints at advantageous locations when you have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Are you running on a UNIX/Linux OS?

Comment: @tk421 yup, on CentOS 7 specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this means that the return address on the stack has been overwritten with 0, probably due to overrunning the end of an on-stack array.  You can trying building with address sanitizer on gcc or clang (if you are using them).  Or you can try running with valgrind to see if it will tell you about invalid memory writes.

Comment: Thanks, address sanitizer seems interesting. Is there a way to tell it to report just the stack-buffer-overflow?